# "Method not allowed" error coming while accessing a WCF from windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, wcf

i have created an Ajax enabled WCF in my web project with a simple method of returning message "Hello World" and have hosted it in the IIS. When i call the WCF from browser it is working and showing the message like

> {"d":"Hello World"}

I created a windows application and added the code as below to access the wcf

```
 BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
            EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:60/wcf");

            ServiceReference2.PurchaseWCFClient objk = new ServiceReference2.PurchaseWCFClient(binding,epa);
            label1.Text = objk.DoWork();
```

But this code

> label1.Text = objk.DoWork();

is returning an error saying that "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed."

i searched a lot in google and tried many ways but nothing works. I am new to WCF and don't have much understating of WCF.

the same function is working if i call WCF from the same project using javascript call or ajax call

this is what my purchaseWCF.svc.cs contains

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class PurchaseWCF
{

    [WebGet()]
    [OperationContract]
    public string DoWork()
    {

        return "Hello World";
    }


}
```

My web.config contains

```
<service name="InfraERP.WCF.PurchaseWCF">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="InfraERP.WCF.PurchaseWCFAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="InfraERP.WCF.PurchaseWCF" />
  </service>
 <behavior name="InfraERP.WCF.PurchaseWCFAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
```

Initially i tried by using like this

```
ServiceReference2.PurchaseWCFClient objk = new ServiceReference2.PurchaseWCFClient();
```

at this time i got error like this "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference2.PurchaseWCF' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."

after that referring to some sites i added code as above and got the "Method not allowed" error
i have wasted one complete day on this... Please help me to find out the problem...

Comment: Did you activate WCF hosting on IIS? For example on how to do it in IIS 2012 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082950/svc-files-in-windows-server-2012-respond-with-405-method-not-allowed

Answer (score 0):

Possible ways to solve your issue,

(i)Remove the Reference completely from your Service references, also remove manually from the config.

(ii)Add the service reference again, check for the Contract name in your service and your client config.